# How can I filter my events array by common _id field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, aggregation

I have a output like this but i wanna filter events array by _id's which is same with parent object _id.I wanna filter it according to this condition.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5cc45eb430aaba3cdc045dc0" ,
        "word": "Pasta",
        "translate": "Makarna",
        "kind": "İsim",
        "exampleSentence": "asljdalsd",
        "__v": 0,
        "events": [
            {
                "_id": "5cc45eb430aaba3cdc045dc0",
                "createdAt": "2019-04-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "TenMinutesLater": "2019-04-27T13:52:25.721Z",
                "OneWeekLater": "2019-05-04T13:52:15.721Z",
                "OneMonthLater": "2019-05-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "FourMonthLater": "2019-08-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5cc45ee630aaba3cdc045dc1",
                "createdAt": "2019-04-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "TenMinutesLater": "2019-04-27T13:52:25.721Z",
                "OneWeekLater": "2019-05-04T13:52:15.721Z",
                "OneMonthLater": "2019-05-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "FourMonthLater": "2019-08-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

***I wanna filter my events array which is have same _id property with parent object _id.How should be my query acording to what I want  ?***

**this is my query**

```
Word.find({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, words) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    const uid = words.map(word => word._id);
    console.log(req.params.id);
    Word.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: {
            $in: uid.map(function(id) {
              return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
            })
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "tests",
          localField: "eventId",
          foreignField: "_id.str",
          as: "events"
        }
      }
    ])
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  });
```

I want the output like this.How I filter it with parent object's _id ?

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5cc45eb430aaba3cdc045dc0" ,
        "word": "Pasta",
        "translate": "Makarna",
        "kind": "İsim",
        "exampleSentence": "asljdalsd",
        "__v": 0,
        "events": [
            {
                "_id": "5cc45eb430aaba3cdc045dc0",
                "createdAt": "2019-04-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "TenMinutesLater": "2019-04-27T13:52:25.721Z",
                "OneWeekLater": "2019-05-04T13:52:15.721Z",
                "OneMonthLater": "2019-05-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "FourMonthLater": "2019-08-27T13:52:15.721Z",
                "__v": 0
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks answer but I finally solved the problem like this.it is working perfectly**

```
Word.find({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, words) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    const uid = words.map(word => word._id);
    Word.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: {
            $in: uid.map(function(id) {
              return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
            })
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "tests",
          localField: "_id.str",
          foreignField: "eventId",
          as: "events"
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          events: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$events",
              as: "event",
              cond: {
                $eq: ["$$event._id", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here $lookup will return all the events that matches localfield/foreign field condition as you might already know. If you want to filter results by some other criteria (which is not very clear from your description) you can use pipeline feature in joined collection (introduced in 3.6). A sample pipeline in $lookup (take from official site) would look like this. So as you can see you can execute match on joined collection and filter your events.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "warehous`enter code here`es",
           let: { order_item: "$item", order_qty: "$ordered" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$stock_item",  "$$order_item" ] },
                         { $gte: [ "$instock", "$$order_qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { stock_item: 0, _id: 0 } }
           ],
           as: "stockdata"
         }
    }
])
```